# 404 when request has url params in Glassfish

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, glassfish, uri, http-status-code-404

Can't for the life of me figure this out. 
I deploy an application to glassfish 3.1.2.

I put a test file in the application's folder at the same level as WEB-INF
called test.html

Now when I access the file like this:
**http://myserver/application/test.html**
It is served out fine as I would expect.

The problem is when the request has parameters attached,i.e.:
**http://myserver/application/test.html?foo=bar**
Glassfish returns 404 because it's looking for a file called
**test.html?foo=bar**

How do I get glassfish to ignore parameters and serve the file requested?

Comment: I am quite sure that this is not Glassfish's fault. That is no valid URL. The host name is missing and you have a triple /.

Comment: That's just the stackoverflow editor adding the extra slashes, I've removed them now.

Comment: I just had a go at replicating the situation that you have described... but I was not able to run into the same problem.  You may want to open an NB issue: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html. SO questions and comments aren't a very good place to isolate bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Netbeans. I've workaround it by making the html file a servlet:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>openid</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/test.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>openid</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/test.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So now, test.html?foo=bar is served out as expected.
It must be that glassfish expects anything that come in with parameters to be a servlet/jsp whatever.